# Can the graph only index indexed parameters?

Tags: events, the-graph

I have an event that looks like this:

```js
    event ItemListed(
        address indexed seller,
        address indexed nftAddress,
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        uint256 price
    );
```

And I'd like to index all 4. However, can the graph only index the indexed parameters? With my graph setup, I have an event handler that looks like:

```js
export function handleItemListed(event: ItemListedEvent): void {
    let itemListed = ItemListed.load(
        getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
    )
    if (!itemListed) {
        itemListed = new ItemListed(
            getIdFromEventParams(event.params.tokenId, event.params.nftAddress)
        )
    }
    itemListed.seller = event.params.seller
    itemListed.nftAddress = event.params.nftAddress
    itemListed.tokenId = event.params.tokenId
    itemListed.price = event.params.price
    itemListed.save()
}
```

However, `price` is not showing up on my playground.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can index non-indexed parameters, so long as it has the ABI. You have to add the variable to your query field!

```
{
  itemListeds(first: 5) {
    id
    seller
    nftAddress
    tokenId
    price
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you know the answer to this related question about non-indexed parameters? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133393/is-the-indexed-keyword-for-a-solidity-event-no-longer-necessary-because-of-sub/133422?noredirect=1#comment155298_133422