# Is the `indexed` keyword for a Solidity event no longer necessary because of subgraphs?

Tags: solidity, events, opcode

Context:
The `indexed` keyword is used for Event fields when we want them to be easily searchable using the JSON-RPC method [eth_newFilter](https://ethereum.github.io/execution-apis/api-documentation/). This was the best way to offchain index the interactions with your smart contract, until [subgraphs](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/about/).

Since a subgraph does not distinguish between indexed Event fields and non-indexed Event fields, this leads me to believe that it is no longer necessary to add the `indexed` keyword to any of my events. Is this true?

If it is true, then this is a benefit for the entire Ethereum community because it means we no longer need to use the `LOG1, LOG2, LOG3, and LOG4` opcodes, and can always use the gas-optimal `LOG0` opcode for our Events.

Answer (score 4):

In events, any `indexed` parameter is emitted as is (reference parameters are hashed). Non `indexed` parameters are **ABI encoded** and stored in `data` log.

The advantage of subgraphs is that you can write scripts that can decide what to do with events **when they find a matching event.**

So even if the parameter is not `indexed`, you can simply ABI decode the `data` part.

> when they find a matching event

This is the key part. The subgraphs you write **cannot react to your events if they can't find them**. So in order for the subgraph to detect your event, you should at the least emit a `non anonymous` event given you don't have the contract address. This way, all the parameters can be ABI encoded in `data` and our subgraph/any script can decode it.

But if you have the contract address, you can also declare it as `anonymous` and still find the event and decode the values emitted.

Comment: This answer is good, but it doesn't answer my original question about "whether indexed is ever worthwhile when using subgraphs".

Comment: From a pure data fetching perspective, subgraphs are faster since they index and store events on their DB for dApps to consume. Filtering plainly through event filters takes a lot of time.

Comment: can you respond to my specific question about use of the "indexed" keyword? I'm not asking about the tradeoffs between using filtering vs. indexing.

Comment: I guess it's your own choice for indexed events, as if anyone wants to build an app on top of your contract and index events with js tools and not a subgraph, it wont be able to filter ;)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question here. I would still recommend using the `indexed` keyword, since subgraphs are just one blockchain indexing technique. There could be other techniques right now or in the future, that benefit from it.